# Jenkins: How do I figure out what is the groovy command for UI block in my jenkins job

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to create a job that will run .groovy files to generate other jobs on my jenkins server. As of Now I know that 'shell()' maps to 'execute shell command'; but how do I figure out what's the groovy equivalent for plugin specific block?

Like I have side bar plugin installed and I don't know th groovy equivalent of the same. How do I get that?
 Is there some documentation in each plugin that specifies its groovy equivalent?

Is there centralized documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Every Jenkins plugin I'm aware of has a page at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org with a link to its source code. There's [the page for the Sidebar-Link Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin).

There's also the [Jobcopy Builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jobcopy+Builder+plugin):

> *This plugin adds "Copy Job" as a build step. You can select how to retrieve choices, including the way to share choices among all jobs.*

And there's also a page how to [Extend Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins) with a *Developing Plugins* section.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. How am I suppose to get the groovy equivalent  of the plugin here? Please help understand

Comment: @RonakAgrawal What do you exactly mean by „_the groovy equivalent of the plugin_“?

Comment: I am using .groovy file to encode the job detail. So when this file is supplied to a job, it will generate other jobs. I know a couple of groovy commands that map to build events; but I am not sure how do I add others.

Comment: By groovy equivalent, I mean the code block that when added to groovy file, will add that event/action to the job generated. Like shell('echo hi')' will add an action- execute a shell command -'echo hi' to the generated job.

Comment: @RonakAgrawal Have you read the _Developing Plugins_ section I linked to? Have you looked into the source codes of plugins that you know are doing what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for pointers. I read and get back. When I read before, it was jenkins source code that I saw. Missed the plugin part.

Comment: Okay, as far as I have figured out; I have to Groovy Eclipse Plugin and then convert the project to groovy project. Is that the way to go about it?
Reference:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+View